# Using Postman with AWS Cognito Auth

Tags: authentication, postman, amazon-cognito, aws-userpools

How can I test my authorized API endpoints with postman?

Requirement: I want to hit the endpoint as an authorized user because the lambda handler mapped to that http event gets the user's identity with `event.requestContext.identity.cognitoIdentityId`, which are not present when the request is signed with my access key and secret key.

I can successfully retrieve get ID, Access, and Refresh Tokens with

```py
import boto3

def initAuth(username, password):
    '''
    Initializes a cognito user in clientId specified
    '''
    cog_client = boto3.client('cognito-idp')
    return response = cog_client.initiate_auth(
            ClientId='4sXXXXXXXXXXXXd7',
            AuthFlow='USER_PASSWORD_AUTH',
            AuthParameters={
                'USERNAME': username,
                'PASSWORD': password
            })
#enddef


def getTokens(data):
    tokens = data['AuthenticationResult']
    return (tokens['AccessToken'], tokens['IdToken'], tokens['RefreshToken'])
#enddef


def main(username, password):
    authSuccess = initAuth(username, password)
    if authSuccess:
        (AccessToken, IdToken, RefreshToken) = getTokens(authSuccess)
        print('AccessToken:', AccessToken, '\n')`enter code here`
        print('IdToken:', IdToken, '\n')
        print('RefreshToken:', RefreshToken, '\n')
#enddef
```

But when I attach a returned Bearer Token to a request in Postman, it doesn't work. It returns with the message:

> not a valid key=value pair (missing equal-sign) in Authorization header: 'Bearer .*

This is apparently because *Bearer* is prepend to the token and Cognito doesn't like that (which is apprently not the case anymore? https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=241945). Either way, I'm still not able to figure this out.

**Edit**

After pasting the token in Authorization and hitting **Preview Request**, the request headers update to

```py
headers = {
    'Content-Type': "application/json",
    'Authorization': "Bearer eyJjdHkiOiJK...........",
    'cache-control': "no-cache",
    'Postman-Token': "e3d1241f-9dd6-4cca-83...."
    }
```

What am I missing? Going a bit crazy here. Thanks

Comment: Does it work if you don't put Bearer in front of the token?

Comment: Can u share your Header info of postman?

Comment: @NinadGaikwad Postman automatically puts Bearer in front of the token, so sadly no.

Comment: Update postman. There are workarounds for this and I think they provided patches for this in newer releases.  https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/4044#issuecomment-463200228

Comment: Same issue. Updated Postman too but no joy. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Updating postman didn't resolve it for me either. Maybe I'm not generating the correct keys? Not sure, but going to take another crack at it this upcoming weekend